# Why is my component's attribute being modified?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura-attribute, helper

I'm building a small component which displays information based on a currently selected object called `metric`.

**Metric Card Component**

```html
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="metricLabelList" type="String[]" default="[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="metric" type="SObject"/>
        <aura:attribute name="metricObjects" type="SObject[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="selectedMetric" type="String" default="Clicks"/>
        <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.metricObjects}" action="{!c.onMetricObjectsChanged}"/>

        <div class="wsm_metric-card wsm_box-shadow">
            <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu" onselect="{! c.selectOption }" class="wsm_select" label="{!v.selectedMetric}" variant="bare-inverse" alternativeText="Show menu">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.metricLabelList}" var="metricOpt">
                    <lightning:menuItem value="{!metricOpt}" label="{!metricOpt}" />
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:buttonMenu>                     
            <div class="current-value slds-m-vertical_x-small">
                <span class="metric-value">{!v.metric.current}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="past-value positive">
                <span></span>
                <span class="value-delta">{!v.metric.previous}</span><span class="percentage-delta"> (-6.72%)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

I'm passing the attributes value from a parent component like this:

```html
<c:Metric_Card metricLabelList="{!v.metricLabels}" metric="{!v.metrics[0]}" metricObjects="{!v.metrics}"></c:Metric_Card>
```

The idea is that the parent component makes a request, fetches the data and then just passes the values to the Metric Card so it displays the information.

In the MC component I have a button which I use to select a different value, look for that value in an array of objects and change the displayed information, however, when i change values, **the array of objects `metricObjects` is being modified without any instruction to do so**.

This is the method I'm using when changing values in the button:

**Metric Card Helper**

```js
selectOption: function(component, event) {
        var selectedItem = event.getParam("value");
        component.set("v.selectedMetric", selectedItem);
        var metric = component.get("v.metricObjects").find(element => {
            return element.label === selectedItem;
        });
        component.set("v.metric", metric);
    }
```

What I get is the following:

After loading the component the first time, my array is correctly defined:

[image]

But after selecting a different value, the same array is modified and now shoes duplicate values or even undefined values (see the "Impressions" object twice now):

[image]

**QUESTION:**
Why is the `metricObjects` array being modified after I select a different value from by button menu, since I'm only directly setting the value of the `metric` object?

Comment: This is a well written post with a lot of useful information about the problem you are facing. However, it does not contain a clear question. Could you please  take a moment to [edit] it's content to just clearly and concisely summarize what you are asking?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Will add that explicitly at the end of the post in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{!...}` is a **two-way** binding. This means that any changes you make to the attribute from the parent will appear to the child, and any changes in the child should also affect the parent. I say "should" because there are some bugs regarding when multiple children share the same parent attribute, not all of them may see the change. Regardless, this is at least expected behavior for the situation at hand.

You can probably use the **one-way** binding technique if you'd like (`{#...}`), but you'll then need to notify the parent of any changes. If that doesn't work, use an internal attribute to copy the data to, and then you can adjust the values that way:

```
<!-- we're in the child component -->
<aura:attribute access="public" type="Metric__c" name="metric" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.metric}" action="{!c.updateMetric}" />
<aura:attribute access="private" type="Metric__c" name="metricCopy" />
```

...

```
updateMetric: function(c, e, h) {
  c.set("v.metricCopy", c.get("v.metric")); // Or whatever else you need to do
}
```

Comment: Noted, however in my case I'm not seeing why that would be an issue, since I'm updating the `metric` variable in the child component, and in that same component the `metricObject` array is the one getting modified as well

Comment: @IvanS95 Correct. You passed in an index in to an array, so when you updated the attribute on the child side, the index in that array also got modified.

Comment: So you are saying that the value stored in `metric` during component intialization (`{!v.metrics[0]}`) is a reference to that object in the `metricsObject` array?

Comment: @IvanS95 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I see, alright so I'll have to find a different way to set an initial metric loaded in each metric card, thank you!